# SD card reader issues mid 2010 MacBook Pro

Tags: hardware, sd-card

I’ve been having a few issues with the sd card reader on my mid 2010 MacBook Pro. A few weeks ago every sd card I inserted I could only read from, but not write to. I know the switch on the sd cards for enabling/disabling writing, and that was not the issue. After some googling I found out there is actually a switch inside the sd card reader, and that had gotten stuck. So I was able to flip that with a paper clip and everything started working again for the past couple of weeks.

Fast forward to today and I had the same issue not being able to write to any sd cards. I figured it was the same issue as before, but the internal switch is in the correct position as well as the one on the sd card. I thought a reboot may fix it, but after trying that without a sd card inserted I can’t get past the grey boot screen. If I turn it off and try to reboot with a sd card inserted it boots fine, but I am still unable to write to any sd cards. It also sounds like there is a faint constant clicking noise coming from around the sd card reader that I have never noticed before. Has anyone experienced this before or have any thoughts on how to fix it?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the built-in card-reader in the MacBook Pro. Most likely the ticking noise is your MacBook Pro's hard drive failing - the SD reader has no moving parts. (BTW/ I've never heard of a write-lock switch _inside_ the card-reader itself.)

Comment: I do mean the built in sd card reader. I hadnt heard of that switch either, but I stumbled across this post - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2618621 and someone said there was an internal switch for card reader.  After messing with that it started working again. I have a ssd, so I don’t think there are any moving parts besides the fans and disk drive. I just find it weird that the noise started the same time I was having issues with the card reader, but like you said there are no moving parts in the card reader. Maybe it is just coincidence and something else is failing with the reader.